# How to derive the mean of inverse-Wishart distribution?

Tags: st.statistics, random-matrices, matrix-theory, matrix-inverse

How to derive the mean of inverse-Wishart distribution in 
[Inverse-Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution)?

I have no idea about it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about the use of Mathematica, e.g. Mean[InverseWishartMatrixDistribution[8, 
   DiagonalMatrix[{2, 1, 3}]]] // MatrixForm $$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right)?$$

Answer (score 2):

If you start from a matrix $A$ that has a Wishart distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom and a $p\times p$ positive-definite scale matrix $\Sigma$ (with $\nu>p+1$), then the inverse $A^{-1}$ has the mean
$$E(A^{-1})=\frac{\Sigma^{-1}}{\nu-p-1}.$$
Note that $A$ itself has mean $E(A)=\nu\Sigma$, so the mean of the inverse is larger than the inverse of the mean (as it should be).

For a derivation, see [Moments for the Inverted Wishart Distribution](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4616090) (1988).

Comment: What is the reason for the condition $\nu > p + 1$? What happens when $\nu = p, p+1$?

Comment: the probability distribution of the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$ vanishes for small $\lambda$ as $\lambda^{(\nu-p-1)/2}$, so the expectation value of $A^{-1}$ will only converge if $\nu-p-1>0$.

Comment: thank you, do you have a reference for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Probability_density_function

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perhaps down-to-earth derivation. Write $A=G^TG = \sum_{i=1}^n g_ig_i^T$ with $g_i\sim N(0,I_d)$ the rows of $G\in R^{n\times d}$. If we had $g_i\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ instead, multiply by $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ and use linearity to reduce the problem to the $g_i\sim N(0,I_d)$ case.

Now $E[A^{-1}]_{i,j}=0$ for $i\ne j$ because $A$ is equal in distribution to $DAD$ where $D=I_d -2e_ie_i^T$ (change the sign of the identity in the $i$-th diagonal element). By symmetry, $E[A^{-1}]_{ii}=\frac1d E[\text{trace}(A^{-1})]$, so we may as well compute $E[trace[A^{-1}]]$.

One version of Stein's formula (also known as integration by parts) is that $E[g_i^T F_(g_i)]=\sum_{j=1}^d E[\frac{\partial}{\partial g_{ij}} F_j(g_i)]$ for almost everywhere differentiable $F:R^d\to R^d$ if the random variables appearing inside expectations are all integrable.

Apply this to $F(g_i)=A^{-1}g_i$ conditionally on $(g_l)_{l\in[n]\setminus \{i\}}$, applying the product rule, first by differentiating the righmost $g_i$ and then by differentiating $A^{-1}$ using $d(A^{-1})=-A^{-1}(dA)A^{-1}$:
\begin{align}
E\Big[g_i^TA^{-1}g_i\Big]
&=
\sum_{j=1}^d E\Big[e_j^T A^{-1} e_j\Big] - E\Big[e_j^T A^{-1}\Big(e_j e_i^TG + G^Te_i e_j^T\Big)A^{-1} g_i\Big]
\\
&= E\Big[ \text{trace}[A] - \text{trace}[A] g_i^TA^{-1}g_i - \sum_{j=1}^d (e_j^TA^{-1}g_i)^2\Big]
\end{align}
and the rightmost term equals $g_i^TA^{-2}g_i$. Summing over $i=1,...,n$ gives
\begin{align}
E\Big[\text{trace}(GA^{-1}G)\Big]& = E\Big[n ~ \text{trace}(A) - \text{trace}(A)\text{trace}(GA^{-1}G^T)-trace[GA^{-2}G] \Big],
\\
d &= E \Big[\text{trace}(A)\Big](n-d-1),
\end{align}
so that $E[A^{-1}]_{ii} = \frac{1}{n-d-1}$ as stated in the accepted answer.